# Equation of Forces for Rocket - The Rocket Equation and Newton's Third Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

Assume a rocket is being vertically accelerated in a homogeneous gravitational field.
In the reference frame of the rocket, the burnt fuel is being exhausted downwards with a velocity of $\Delta u$.
We ignore air resistance.

In a small time interval $dt$, the rocket loses the mass $dm$.
So the momentum of the rocket in this time step changes (because of the exhausted gas) by

$$ dp_a = dm\Delta u \tag{1} $$

Since the rocket is in an homogeneous gravitational field, it is also being accelerated downwards. The corresponding change in momentum is

$$ dp_g = -mgdt \tag{2} $$

so the velocity of the rocket changes by

$$ dv = \frac{dp_a + dp_g}{m} \tag{3} $$

so the equation of motion for the rocket is

$$ dv = \frac{dm}{m}\Delta u - gdt \tag{4} $$

We get $v(t)$ by integrating (4) over $t$.

Now, I do get all that. At least I think I do. We basically use the conservation of momentum. I mainly wrote the above solution so we are on the same page.

My problem is about Newton's third law. At least I think it is. Basically I want to write down an equation of forces.

So let's assume we have our rocket. We have the two constants $v_g, g > 0$. Now it's clear that we have $F_G=-mg$ pointing downwards and "pulling" the rocket down:

[image]

The gad particle are being exhausted downwards with the speed $-v_g$. So we get

$p_a(t)=-m(t)v_g \quad \Rightarrow \quad F_a(t)=\dot{p}_a = -\dot{m}(t)v_g \tag{4, 5}$

So $F_a$ points downwards and because of Newtons third law $-F_a$ points upwards. It's clear: The particles push themselves off of the rocket and the rocket "pushes back".

There are no other forces. So we end up with:

$F_{\text{Result}} = F_G + F_a - F_a = F_G \tag{6}$

Where's my problem? Why can't I solve it like that? Why can't I find a force for the acceleration? I mean, one can imagine that I just stand there and push it, no?

Comment: the force the rocket is doing to the gas should not be included, the expelled gas is not part of the rocket and the force this gas does on the rocket was taken into account in the first equation you wrote

Comment: I'm resolving the problem after (4). The burning of the fuel produces a continuous force. I'd need an argument to drop that force from (6).

Comment: action and reaction never act on the same "object"

Comment: Oh, yeah that was my mistake. thanks :) You might make an nswer for that.